# angular 2+ fetch specific value from local json file

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I want to fetch only a certain object from the file. But I somehow only can fetch the entire data from the file.

[image]

So far my method to fetch the data looks like this:

```
getGeoCityFromLocalFile(lon, lat) {
    return this.http.get('/assets/city-list.json')
    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res => {
         If(res.coord.lon === lon && res.coord.lat === lat) {
             this.cityStatsStorage = res;
             console.log(this.cityStatsStorage);
             return this.cityStatsStorage;
         }
    });
}
```

I want to fetch only this Object where the `lon an lan` Input are the same.

Comment: You cannot do that. You need a backend service (Java, c#, PHP.. or likes) to handle your request and pass you only the desired data.

Comment: Actually why not, if he dont mind sending whole data each time and filtering in the frontend, why not?

Comment: If you are directly referring to a json file without any backend service to handle your request, you will get the entire JSON back. Then you need to filter your json response with your angular code to get your desired filtered data

Comment: @vicbyte His questions says "I want to fetch only a certain object", in my second comment I have talked about handling it on the client side

Comment: the json file is really really big so i need really only this specific object in my respond regarding on the inputs lot and lan. So i really need to implement a backend service on my own. Are there any other solutions. Once Again: I really want this specific object to fetch.

Comment: As we mentioned, you can filter both on backend and frontend. Its just a matter of choice, as in, if you can live with sending whole data each time to user, or would you rather just want to send a small portion of it in exchange for some server processing power :)

Comment: i guess for now i'll do the solution with the loop (fetch the big ass file and filter it with the loop for the specific object) later on ill need to implement something like a script (the file is 30MB big!!) but nontheless thank u all for the fast answers!

Comment: Well then, you definetly need to move it to the backend. Database will be a good idea also, as it will speed up searching quite a bit (or use some in-memory caching, but thats assuming the collection wont grow much).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in here:

```
If(res.coord.lon === lon && res.coord.lat === lat)
```

Res is an array and not a single object, so you would need a loop. Example:

```
for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
   if (res[i].coord.lon === lon && res[i].coord.lat === lat){
      this.cityStatsStorage = res[i];
      console.log(this.cityStatsStorage);
      return this.cityStatsStorage;
   }
}
```